# Cannot add attributes in Session for Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Whenever I set a session attribute and try to access it, it comes as 'null' for the first time and then it works just fine. I'm using Spring Webflow, and have to set that attribute the first time the page is loaded.

I've tried using a HandlerInterceptorAdapter for setting a specific attribute in my application. I added an attribute in the postHandle() method like this :

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("attrib") == null){    
            session.setAttribute("attrib", attrib);
    } 
}
```

On debugging I found that the session came as null, which on further analysis came out to be a bug by Spring Webflow itself, so I overrode the 'handle' method of the FlowHandlerAdapter file like so :

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        super.handle(request, response, handler);
        ServletExternalContext context = createServletExternalContext(request, response);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if( session != null && context != null && context.getSessionMap().get("attrib") == null){           
                    context.getSessionMap().put("attrib", attrib);
}
    return null;
}
```

The session here is null as well for the first time around.

I've even tried defining an action before the view is rendered in an `<action-state>` block, inside the view state in a `<on-entry>` block, and then even a `<on-render>` block. Nothing seems to work!